# Classification accuracy is too low (Word2Vec)

Tags: python, nlp, classification, word2vec, emotion

i'm working on an Multi-Label Emotion Classification problem to be solved by word2vec. this is my code that i've learned from a couple of tutorials. now the accuracy is very low. about 0.02 which is telling me something is wrong in my code. but i cannot find it. i tried this code for TF-IDF and BOW (obviously except word2vec part) and i got much better accuracy scores such as 0.28, but it seems this one is somehow wrong:

```
np.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)
wv = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format("E:\\GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin", binary=True)
wv.init_sims(replace=True)

#Pre-Processor Function
pre_processor = TextPreProcessor(
    omit=['url', 'email', 'percent', 'money', 'phone', 'user',
        'time', 'url', 'date', 'number'],
    
    normalize=['url', 'email', 'percent', 'money', 'phone', 'user',
        'time', 'url', 'date', 'number'],
     
    segmenter="twitter", 
    
    corrector="twitter", 
    
    unpack_hashtags=True,
    unpack_contractions=True,
    
    tokenizer=SocialTokenizer(lowercase=True).tokenize,
    
    dicts=[emoticons]
)

#Averaging Words Vectors to Create Sentence Embedding
def word_averaging(wv, words):
    all_words, mean = set(), []
    
    for word in words:
        if isinstance(word, np.ndarray):
            mean.append(word)
        elif word in wv.vocab:
            mean.append(wv.syn0norm[wv.vocab[word].index])
            all_words.add(wv.vocab[word].index)

    if not mean:
        logging.warning("cannot compute similarity with no input %s", words)
        # FIXME: remove these examples in pre-processing
        return np.zeros(wv.vector_size,)

    mean = gensim.matutils.unitvec(np.array(mean).mean(axis=0)).astype(np.float32)
    return mean

def  word_averaging_list(wv, text_list):
    return np.vstack([word_averaging(wv, post) for post in text_list ])

#Secondary Word-Averaging Method
def get_mean_vector(word2vec_model, words):
# remove out-of-vocabulary words
words = [word for word in words if word in word2vec_model.vocab]
if len(words) >= 1:
    return np.mean(word2vec_model[words], axis=0)
else:
    return []

#Loading data
raw_train_tweets = pandas.read_excel('E:\\train.xlsx').iloc[:,1] #Loading all train tweets
train_labels = np.array(pandas.read_excel('E:\\train.xlsx').iloc[:,2:13]) #Loading corresponding train labels (11 emotions)

raw_test_tweets = pandas.read_excel('E:\\test.xlsx').iloc[:,1] #Loading 300 test tweets
test_gold_labels = np.array(pandas.read_excel('E:\\test.xlsx').iloc[:,2:13]) #Loading corresponding test labels (11 emotions)
print("please wait")

#Pre-Processing
train_tweets=[]
test_tweets=[]
for tweets in raw_train_tweets:
    train_tweets.append(pre_processor.pre_process_doc(tweets))

for tweets in raw_test_tweets:
    test_tweets.append(pre_processor.pre_process_doc(tweets))

#Vectorizing 
train_array = word_averaging_list(wv,train_tweets)
test_array = word_averaging_list(wv,test_tweets)

#Predicting and Evaluating    
clf = LabelPowerset(LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs', C=1, class_weight=None))
clf.fit(train_array,train_labels)
predicted= clf.predict(test_array)
intersect=0
union=0
accuracy=[]
for i in range(0,3250): #i have 3250 test tweets.
    for j in range(0,11): #11 emotions
        if predicted[i,j]&test_gold_labels[i,j]==1:
            intersect+=1
        if predicted[i,j]|test_gold_labels[i,j]==1:
            union+=1
    
    accuracy.append(intersect/union) if union !=0 else accuracy.append(0.0)
    intersect=0
    union=0
print(np.mean(accuracy))
```

The Result:

```
0.4674498168498169
```

And i printed predicted variable (for tweet 0 to 10) to see how it looks like:

```
  (0, 0)    1
  (0, 2)    1
  (2, 0)    1
  (2, 2)    1
  (3, 4)    1
  (3, 6)    1
  (4, 0)    1
  (4, 2)    1
  (5, 0)    1
  (5, 2)    1
  (6, 0)    1
  (6, 2)    1
  (7, 0)    1
  (7, 2)    1
  (8, 4)    1
  (8, 6)    1
  (9, 3)    1
  (9, 8)    1
```

as you can see, it only show 1's. for example (6,2) means in tweet number 6, emotion number 2 is 1. (9,8) means in tweet number 9, emotion number 8 is 1. the other emotions considered as 0. but you can imagine it like this to better understand what i've done in Accuracy method:

```
gold emotion for tweet 0:      [1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1]
predicted emotion for tweet 0: [1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

i've used union and intersect for the indexes one by one. 1 to 1. 1 to 1. 0 to 1, until gold emotion 11 to predicted emotion 11. i did this for all tweets in two for loops.

## Creating Word2Vec vectors on my tweets:

now i want to use gensim to create Word2Vec vectors on my tweet dataset. i changed some parts of the code above as below:

```
#Averaging Words Vectors to Create Sentence Embedding
def word_averaging(wv, words):
    all_words, mean = set(), []

    for word in words:
        if isinstance(word, np.ndarray):
            mean.append(word)
        elif word in wv.vocab:
            mean.append(wv.syn0norm[wv.vocab[word].index])
            all_words.add(wv.vocab[word].index)

    if not mean:
        logging.warning("cannot compute similarity with no input %s", words)
        # FIXME: remove these examples in pre-processing
        return np.zeros(wv.vector_size,)

    mean = gensim.matutils.unitvec(np.array(mean).mean(axis=0)).astype(np.float32)
    return mean

def  word_averaging_list(wv, text_list):
    return np.vstack([word_averaging(wv, post) for post in text_list ])

#Loading data
raw_aggregate_tweets = pandas.read_excel('E:\\aggregate.xlsx').iloc[:,0] #Loading all train tweets

raw_train_tweets = pandas.read_excel('E:\\train.xlsx').iloc[:,1] #Loading all train tweets
train_labels = np.array(pandas.read_excel('E:\\train.xlsx').iloc[:,2:13]) #Loading corresponding train labels (11 emotions)

raw_test_tweets = pandas.read_excel('E:\\test.xlsx').iloc[:,1] #Loading 300 test tweets
test_gold_labels = np.array(pandas.read_excel('E:\\test.xlsx').iloc[:,2:13]) #Loading corresponding test labels (11 emotions)
print("please wait")

#Pre-Processing
aggregate_tweets=[]
train_tweets=[]
test_tweets=[]
for tweets in raw_aggregate_tweets:
    aggregate_tweets.append(pre_processor.pre_process_doc(tweets))

for tweets in raw_train_tweets:
    train_tweets.append(pre_processor.pre_process_doc(tweets))

for tweets in raw_test_tweets:
    test_tweets.append(pre_processor.pre_process_doc(tweets))
    
print(len(aggregate_tweets))
#Vectorizing 
w2v_model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(aggregate_tweets, min_count = 10, size = 300, window = 8)

print(w2v_model.wv.vectors.shape)

train_array = word_averaging_list(w2v_model.wv,train_tweets)
test_array = word_averaging_list(w2v_model.wv,test_tweets)
```

but i get this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-8a5fe4dbf144> in <module>
    110 print(w2v_model.wv.vectors.shape)
    111 
--> 112 train_array = word_averaging_list(w2v_model.wv,train_tweets)
    113 test_array = word_averaging_list(w2v_model.wv,test_tweets)
    114 

<ipython-input-1-8a5fe4dbf144> in word_averaging_list(wv, text_list)
     70 
     71 def  word_averaging_list(wv, text_list):
---> 72     return np.vstack([word_averaging(wv, post) for post in text_list ])
     73 
     74 #Averaging Words Vectors to Create Sentence Embedding

<ipython-input-1-8a5fe4dbf144> in <listcomp>(.0)
     70 
     71 def  word_averaging_list(wv, text_list):
---> 72     return np.vstack([word_averaging(wv, post) for post in text_list ])
     73 
     74 #Averaging Words Vectors to Create Sentence Embedding

<ipython-input-1-8a5fe4dbf144> in word_averaging(wv, words)
     58             mean.append(word)
     59         elif word in wv.vocab:
---> 60             mean.append(wv.syn0norm[wv.vocab[word].index])
     61             all_words.add(wv.vocab[word].index)
     62 

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what your `TextPreProcessor` or `SocialTokenizer` classes might do. You should edit your question to either show their code, or show a few examples of the resulting texts to make sure it's doing what you expect. (For example: show the first few and last few entries of `all_tweets`.)

It's not likely that your line `all_tweets = train_tweets.append(test_tweets)` is doing what you expect. (It'll put the entire list `test_tweets` as the final element of `all_tweets` – but then return `None` which you assign to `all_tweets`. Your `Word2Vec` model might then be empty - you should enable INFO logging to watch its progress & review the output for anomalies, and add code post-training to print some details about the model that confirm useful training occurred.)

Are you sure `train_tweets` is the right format for your pipeline to `.fit()` against? (The texts sent to `Word2Vec` training seem to have been tokenized via a `.split()`, but the texts in the `pandas.Series` `train_tweets` may never have been tokenized.)

Generally, a good idea is to enable logging, and add more code after each step confirming, via checking property values or printing excerpts of the longer collections, that each step has had the intended effect.

Comment: Thanks for helping me. i've changed the source code (embedding part). take a look please. also i printed all my results.

Comment: any thoughts..?

Comment: Thanks for the extended question. I'm not sure the main issue, but some things to consider: (1) your `word_averaging()` may be doing more than you need - in particular, using the `_norm` vectors & then forcing the result to unit-vec may be losing valuable magnitude info. (2) it's not clear why you're changing `train_tweets` & `test_tweets` back to a `pandas.Series` - that's not the format later steps need. …

Comment: (3) Are you sure all your classifiers are appropriate for multiple labels? Can you look at, & show in question, the multi-label 'predictions' that are being made? (4) Is `accuracy_score()` treating a prediction as correct only if all labels are correct, or treating each individual label-or-not as one prediction to test? (5) Is there a pattern to the errors: are some labels predicted well but not others? Are the successes associated with items where there are more/better training data?

Comment: Thank you for spending time to help me, i'm really in a hard situation. let me answer your questions. (1) to be honest i found this averaging function from a tutorial. if you have a suggestion about omitting a certain part of it, just let me know. (2) forget this part. i tried the code without it and the result was the same. now i removed the .Series part.

Comment: (3) i don't understand what you mean by showing in question? about classifiers i'm sure  using the Logistic Regression is just like what i did. i used problem transformation (Label PowerSet) which is best way to counter multi-label problems. forget other classifiers and only consider Logistic Regression for now.(4) really i don't know how it works. i will search for it if it's important?(5) i don't know this one too. but now i use F1 score and Hamming Loss too in my code to clarify the results better. now, have i written any useful info? or you suggest me to check for the unanswered questions?

Comment: I edited the code and now you can see F1 score and Hamming Loss too. btw, it worth to note that i've gotten the result below with TF-IDF (using NRC Lexicon as vocabulary): `Accuracy =  0.26666666666666666
F1 score =  0.5611402850712679
Hamming loss =  0.17727272727272728` the weird part is how TF-IDF can be better that Word2Vec? do you think my Word2Vec code is wrong somehow?

Comment: It's good to focus on one method, such as Logistic Regression, at a time. It might also be useful to 1st focus on single-label classification, and just one measure (such as overall accuracy), while you are still getting basic things working. I can't author or walk you through updated code, I'm just pointing out: that averaging function looks overcomplicated & you might do better to use non-unit-normed vectors. (So: you're copying from a suboptimal place.)

Comment: TF-IDF-based classification might work very well; you shouldn't assume that a crude average-of-word2vec-vectors, which compresses the text to just the 300 dimensions of the word-vectors - where the word-vectors come from an older, other-domain (news story) training domain, would do better! In particular, if there are novel, highly-indicative words in your data, TF-IDF will retain them, but they'll be silently ignored if they weren't in Google's 2014 news-story word-vectors.

Comment: Still, it looks like the two techniques are in the same ballpark on your measure: 0.27 accuracy TF-IDF, 0.25 on your word2vec-average-into-LabelPowerset-LogisticRegression results above. (And, I'm not sure `LabelPowerset` is a good way to do this, so again, I'd simplify to one-label-at-a-time classification, and master that, before moving on to multilabel.)

Comment: Thanks again. i've changed the averaging function. please look at `#Secondary Word-Averaging Method` and `#Secondary Vectorizing` lines in the code and say your opinion about it. it's the most simple averaging function. the Accuracy with this method is `0.22`. 0.03 percents lower than previous method. btw i'm downloading a good pre-trained word2vec which is trained on 550 millions tweets. i think it's better for my case.

Comment: Assuming your running code is properly indented, that's a more straightforward averaging method. (You may want to return some default vector of the right size, such as an all-zeros vector, when there are no known words, rather than the empty list `[]`.) A tweet-based set of word-vectors might be far better; best would be training on your own subset of tweets, if you have enough tweets & examples of all relevant words – because the lingo used in subsets of tweets of certain languages/topics may be very unique & rapidly-evolving.)

Comment: Finally, I'd still recommend starting with single-label classification, first, to make things more simple & easy to review interim results at each step, & study individual wrong-classifications, before moving on to multi-label. (I'm still not clear if, for a target prediction `[1, 0, 1, 0]`, and a classifier prediction `[1, 0, 0, 0]`, your evaluation is considering that to be 0% accurate  – not exactly right – or 75% accurate – because 3 of the 4 labels are correct.)

Comment: I tried the code on binary classification. on 1 emotion column instead of 11. my accuracy score is 0.80. do i need to try single label too? or binary is enough?. i think the problem could be my prediction method. but i don't know any other way for prediction. how should i find out this (as you said):for a target prediction [1, 0, 1, 0], and a classifier prediction [1, 0, 0, 0], your evaluation is considering that to be 0% accurate – not exactly right – or 75% accurate – because 3 of the 4 labels are correct. do you have a suggestion to see how my prediction works?

Comment: I'm pretty sure 'binary classification' (whether a single label applies or not) has already covered the 'single label' case. With that (seemingly-working) example, you could now do 11 different, separate binary-classifications, one for each of your 'emotions' - to test/verify how well those work – before attempting to train/test a multi-label classifier. (Since in many cases the multi-label will just be an ensemble of single-label classifiers inside, the actual results, for each individual TEXT,EMOTION prediction, should be similar.)

Comment: To better understand what your `accuracy_score()` method is doing with multi-label predictions/gold-standards, take a closer look at a tiny fragment of what it's doing in one of your cases. For example, look at the values of `accuracy_score(test_gold_labels[0:1], predicted[0:1])`, and `test_gold_labels[0:1]`, and `predicted[0:1]`. (Or, other tiny 1 or several item ranges of your data.) Are the percentage-accuracies it reports consistent with "all must match" or "each column checked separately"?

Comment: I posted a second answer for a more clear result. please check it. i did what you said and now it seems the Accuracy score is based on "all must match". in Part One i did binary classification per each column (emotion) and in Part Two i tried to find out what exactly prediction do. check it out please. thanks. i think the Multi-Label classification must be  based on "all must match" method? if so, my code is doing correct and the problem is the overall complexity of Multi-Label task. what do you think?

Comment: You should not post things that aren't actual answers-to-your-questions as 'Answers'. It does make sense to edit or extent your question, to add details, as long as it's the same question. Make your additions in the right place, and I'l take a look.

Comment: Ok, sry. i deleted it and extended the main post as Evaluating Part One and Two. take a look now. tnx

Comment: That your single-label accuracies seem good is an indicator something useful is happening. But, you're incorrectly doing `fit()` for every row, rather than once on the whole training set - which may be fouling your results,

Comment: But your multi-label results have a bigger problem. The output seems to indicate, for example, that your `test_gold_labels[0]` is the array `[1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1]`. But your `predicted[0]` doesn't look anything like that - it instead prints as `   (0, 0)   1\n  (0, 2)    1`. That seems like it might be a totally different (sparse) array-format. Are you sure you're using `LabelPowerset` and its `.predict()` method the right way, and converting the result into a compatible format before scoring its results using `accuracy_score()` against your gold labels?

Comment: About fitting i think it's not important. because my task is multi-label and i just used binary for testing it. about predicting, i think for example `(0,0) 1` says the first index of `[1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1]` is 1. it only shows the 1s. for example tweet number 8 which is `[0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0]`, the predicted result is: `(0,4) 1` and `(0,6) 1` as you can see in the labels. what is your opinion?

Comment: Check to see if `accuracy_score()` works the way you think it does, with the object types you're feeding it, with some alternate example input. Related: do you know yet the answer to my concern above, whether for a target prediction [1, 0, 1, 0], and a classifier prediction [1, 0, 0, 0], your evaluation is considering that to be 0% accurate – not exactly right – or 75% accurate – because 3 of the 4 labels are correct? Whichever it's doing, is that what you want? What, if any, are your remaining concerns, and should they perhaps be a new more focused-question?

Comment: Yes, if looks like your `.fit()` for the single-label case is ok, as each fit is on the whole training set, and you're only printing summaries. (I was momentarily confused by the alternate per-prediction loop in your other setup.) But note also, that if you're predicting 11 separate binary fields, and achieving about an 80% accuracy on each, the chance of all 11 being correct for a single item will only be about (0.80)^11, or about 9%. So maybe everything is working now?

Comment: I'm glad it's working better! I don't quite understand the choice of that score calculation, as opposed to more simple classic 'accuracy'  (total_correct_individual_emotion_predictions)/(total_predictions). That simpler score would give a value more like the average of all your individual-emotion scores. (I haven't looked at your external link, as I don't recognize `ibb.co` domain & a quick Google search talks about it mostly in context of malware.) But, if for some reason that's a required/better measure for you, that's OK. You can now compare that score across alternate multi-label methods.

Comment: I found the problem. better to say we found it! you really helped me so much. actually there wasn't any problem! the accuracy score was working fine, but as you said, it ONLY predict a tweet accurate if all emotions (labels) are correct. for example predicted tweet is: [1,1,1,0,0] and gold label tweet is: [1,1,1,0,1], the Accuracy Score return 0% accurate. but, as you said, i should have checked for my evaluation metrics to see what do i need? a prediction like this? or a comparative prediction (for example a 66% Accuracy). now read the below comment please

Comment: Look at the Accuracy metric which i need to work based on: `https://imgur.com/nVwsUdF`. as you can see it's a comparative metric (i hope i can understand you due to my medium English). i changed my code above and deleted the previous parts. take a loot at #Predicting and Evaluating part and goes on. i tried to implement this Accuracy method and i think it's ok now. you can see the Accuracy score increased greatly from 25 to 46! now please check it and see if i implemented it correctly. just let me know if you can't understand what i've done. then i explain it better. thanks again

Comment: sorry i thought you would see my comments tomorrow (in our time). i changed the upload site above. it was from imgBB. idk why the URL was like that. and i added some extra info at the bottom of code (after result part). this second photo will help to find out what i've done: `https://imgur.com/tJDi2Jz`

Comment: Now that Accuracy part problem solved, i want to use my tweet data set for creating Word2Vec vectors, but i get an error. would you please check the "Creating Word2Vec vectors on my tweets" part in the code above? btw, i don't know how to make my Averaging method simpler as you said in one of your comments

Comment: This sounds like a new question, which should be posted as a new, self-contained, complete question - where I or others can answer it without the long comment history/revisions here. Good luck!