# Getting error on averaging Word2Vec crerated vectors

Tags: python, nlp, classification, word2vec, emotion

i want to use gensim to create Word2Vec vectors on my tweet dataset. the code is for multi-label emotion classification based on tweets. i have aggregated tweets file which contains 107k tweets. i used this for creating Word2Vec vectors based on. my code:

```
np.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)

#Pre-Processor Function
pre_processor = TextPreProcessor(
    omit=['url', 'email', 'percent', 'money', 'phone', 'user',
        'time', 'url', 'date', 'number'],
    
    normalize=['url', 'email', 'percent', 'money', 'phone', 'user',
        'time', 'url', 'date', 'number'],
     
    segmenter="twitter", 
    
    corrector="twitter", 
    
    unpack_hashtags=True,
    unpack_contractions=True,
    
    tokenizer=SocialTokenizer(lowercase=True).tokenize,
    
    dicts=[emoticons]
)

#Averaging Words Vectors to Create Sentence Embedding
def word_averaging(wv, words):
    all_words, mean = set(), []
    
    for word in words:
        if isinstance(word, np.ndarray):
            mean.append(word)
        elif word in wv.vocab:
            mean.append(wv.syn0norm[wv.vocab[word].index])
            all_words.add(wv.vocab[word].index)

    if not mean:
        logging.warning("cannot compute similarity with no input %s", words)
        # FIXME: remove these examples in pre-processing
        return np.zeros(wv.vector_size,)

    mean = gensim.matutils.unitvec(np.array(mean).mean(axis=0)).astype(np.float32)
    return mean

def  word_averaging_list(wv, text_list):
    return np.vstack([word_averaging(wv, post) for post in text_list ])

#Loading data
raw_aggregate_tweets = pandas.read_excel('E:\\aggregate.xlsx').iloc[:,0] #Loading all tweets to have a bigger word2vec corpus

raw_train_tweets = pandas.read_excel('E:\\train.xlsx').iloc[:,1] #Loading all train tweets
train_labels = np.array(pandas.read_excel('E:\\train.xlsx').iloc[:,2:13]) #Loading corresponding train labels (11 emotions)

raw_test_tweets = pandas.read_excel('E:\\test.xlsx').iloc[:,1] #Loading all test tweets
test_gold_labels = np.array(pandas.read_excel('E:\\test.xlsx').iloc[:,2:13]) #Loading corresponding test labels (11 emotions)
print("please wait")

#Pre-Processing
aggregate_tweets=[]
train_tweets=[]
test_tweets=[]
for tweets in raw_aggregate_tweets:
    aggregate_tweets.append(pre_processor.pre_process_doc(tweets))

for tweets in raw_train_tweets:
    train_tweets.append(pre_processor.pre_process_doc(tweets))

for tweets in raw_test_tweets:
    test_tweets.append(pre_processor.pre_process_doc(tweets))


#Vectorizing 
w2v_model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(aggregate_tweets, min_count = 10, size = 300, window = 8)


train_array = word_averaging_list(w2v_model.wv,train_tweets)
test_array = word_averaging_list(w2v_model.wv,test_tweets)
```

but i get this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-8a5fe4dbf144> in <module>
    110 print(w2v_model.wv.vectors.shape)
    111 
--> 112 train_array = word_averaging_list(w2v_model.wv,train_tweets)
    113 test_array = word_averaging_list(w2v_model.wv,test_tweets)
    114 

<ipython-input-1-8a5fe4dbf144> in word_averaging_list(wv, text_list)
     70 
     71 def  word_averaging_list(wv, text_list):
---> 72     return np.vstack([word_averaging(wv, post) for post in text_list ])
     73 
     74 #Averaging Words Vectors to Create Sentence Embedding

<ipython-input-1-8a5fe4dbf144> in <listcomp>(.0)
     70 
     71 def  word_averaging_list(wv, text_list):
---> 72     return np.vstack([word_averaging(wv, post) for post in text_list ])
     73 
     74 #Averaging Words Vectors to Create Sentence Embedding

<ipython-input-1-8a5fe4dbf144> in word_averaging(wv, words)
     58             mean.append(word)
     59         elif word in wv.vocab:
---> 60             mean.append(wv.syn0norm[wv.vocab[word].index])
     61             all_words.add(wv.vocab[word].index)
     62 

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details. what is this error of site? my god. i don't have any more details. sorry i have to do this to bypass the error.

## Second averaging method

```
#Averaging Words Vectors to Create Sentence Embedding
def get_mean_vector(word2vec_model, words):
    # remove out-of-vocabulary words
    words = [word for word in words if word in word2vec_model.vocab]
    if len(words) >= 1:
        return np.mean(word2vec_model[words], axis=0)
    else:
        return np.zeros(word2vec_model.vector_size)

#Vectorizing 
w2v_model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(aggregate_tweets, min_count = 11, size = 400, window = 18, sg=1)

train_array=[]
test_array=[]
for tweet in train_tweets:
    vec = get_mean_vector(w2v_model.wv, tweet)
    if len(vec) > 0:
        train_array.append(vec)
        
for tweet in test_tweets:
    vec = get_mean_vector(w2v_model.wv, tweet)
    if len(vec) > 0:
        test_array.append(vec)
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Have you done any debugging? How does the second method relate to the first?

Answer (score 1):

The error "'NoneType' object is not subscriptable" means you've tried to subscript (index-access with `[]`) a variable that is actually `None`.

Looking at the line highlighted, `wv.syn0norm` is probably `None`.

It doesn't automatically exist: it's only created when needed, as for example by a `.most_similar()` operation. But you can manually trigger its creation, once your training is done, by calling `.init_sims()`:

```py
w2v_model.wv.init_sims()
```

(Note that you'll probably be getting a deprecation warning from your code: that property is renamed `vectors_norm` in recent gensim versions. Also, using these unit-length-normalized vectors may not be as good, for some purposes, as the raw vectors.)

Comment: Great! it worked. but as i'm new to this field and don't understand much of your tips, i tried the code with another averaging method which is more simpler. please take a look at Second averaging method part and tell me your opinion about it. this second method gave me 1% more accuracy in compare to the previous one. thanks.

Comment: Yes, that is a second averaging function.

Comment: And is there necessity to use `w2v_model.wv.init_sims()` again?

Comment: You should really try it, to see if there's an error or not. It's should be faster & easier than asking!

Comment: :))) i had tried it man, before asking here. it worked fine. but i thought maybe i must use that. sorry for asking too much. i'm working on this for my thesis and really needs to be well in all aspects.

Comment: Sure, but I'd already mentioned in our previous long conversation that you could try the non-normed vectors, or the normed vectors - both are ok choices. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60738355/classification-accuracy-is-too-low-word2vec#comment107646693_60766365). And here I'd mentioned that the reason for `init_sims()` was to create the normed vectors & prevent the `None` error. If you're not using the normed vectors, and not getting a `None` error, and are even getting slightly better results, I'd not worry about a method that was only suggested for a specific earlier reason.

Comment: I hadn't understand much of your explanations. that why i asked again. now i've gotten what you mean. thanks again.

Comment: No worries, glad you've made such progress & happy to have helped!